# Search for apps based on language

Tags: applications, google-play-store, 2.3-gingerbread, 3.0-honeycomb, languages

Can I search for  Android APPs that are in Hebrew or Kurdish?
or are all apps automatically translated into all languages?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I search for Android APPs that are in Hebrew or Kurdish?

No. AFAICT, there is nothing that marks the language used in the app.

> Are all apps automatically translated into all languages?

No. The complexity of *reliable* machine translation so is currently beyond our current technology; natural language processing and machine translation is still a hot research topic.